# Разделить аудиофайл на куски и переконвертировать в другой формат

Tags: аудио, ffmpeg

Как с помощью ffmpeg разделить аудиофайл на куски длинной не более 20 секунд и переконвертировать их в другой формат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разделения на части нужно указать флаги `-f segment -segment_time 20` и шаблон выходных файлов. Для переконвертирования просто указать расширение выходных файлов.

Итого:

`ffmpeg -i input.ext1 -f segment -segment_time 20 input%d.ext2`